# Some organisation's GitHub repositories are missing for continuous deployment on Azure

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops

**Context**

We use the *Deployment options* of our Azure *App Service* to link it to one of our GitHub repositories, so that every pull request is automatically deployed.

We gave Azure access to our GitHub organisation via a dedicated GitHub account, which is set as an owner of the organisation (as an owner, the user is *admin* of all the repositories of the organisation).

Our organisation has 386 GitHub repositories.

**Problem**

Some of the repositories that we used to deploy are not available in the list of repositories anymore. Some others are still available.

**What we checked**

- The missing repositories belong to our organisation.
- Our dedicated GitHub user is admin of those missing repositories.
- The 3rd-party access has been granted to Azure in GitHub (*Azure Management Portal - Primary* & *Azure Management Portal - Secondary*).

**What we tried**

- We merged a PR in one of the missing repositories. It did not change anything.

Comment: We also tried to create a new GitHub user, we invited him as a member of our organisation and we granted him the admin rights on 6 specific repositories. Only 3 of them are displayed in Azure...

Comment: It looks like the `SetupOAuth` HTTP request emitted by the Azure Console only returns a subset of the repositories, so the problem has nothing to do with the console itself.

Comment: It works when using the Azure CLI: `az appservice web source-control config`...